# Docker-Compose bind volume only if exists

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a volume which uses `bind` to share a local directory. Sometimes this directory doesn't exist and docker exits with the error

```
Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /srv/share.
```

How can I tell docker-compose to look for the source directory and use it if it exists or to continue without mounting the volume if the source directory doesn't exist?

Volume example:

```
  - type: bind
    read_only: true
    source: /srv/share/
    target: /srv/share/
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How can I tell docker-compose to look for the directory and use it if it exists or to continue without said volume if errors?

As far I am aware you can't do conditional logic to mount a volume, but i am getting around it in a project of mine, like this:

```
version: "2.1"

services:

  elixir:
    image: elixir:alpine
    volumes:
      - ${VOLUME_SOURCE:-/dev/null}:${VOLUME_TARGET:-/.devnull}:ro
```

Here I am using `/dev/null` as the fallback, but in my real project I just use an empty file to do the mapping.

This `${VOLUME_SOURCE:-/dev/null}` is how bash works with default values for variables not set, and docker compose supports them.

#### Testing it without setting the env vars

```
$ sudo docker-compose run --rm elixir sh 

/ # ls -al /.devnull 
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     root        1,   3 May 21 12:27 /.devnull
```

#### Testing it with the env vars set

Creating the `.env` file:

```
$ printf "VOLUME_SOURCE=./testing \nVOLUME_TARGET=/testing\n" > .env && cat .env
VOLUME_SOURCE=./testing 
VOLUME_TARGET=/testing
```

Creating the volume for test purposes:

```
$ mkdir testing && touch testing/test.txt && ls -al testing
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 exadra37 exadra37 4096 May 22 13:12 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 exadra37 exadra37 4096 May 22 13:12 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 exadra37 exadra37    0 May 22 13:12 test.txt
```

Running the container:

```
$ sudo docker-compose run --rm elixir sh
/ # ls -al /testing/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x    2 1000     1000          4096 May 22 12:01 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 May 22 12:07 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 1000     1000             0 May 22 12:01 test.txt
/ #
```

Comment: This solution seems to have been posted a few months ago already, but for me this was the solution to conditionally add mount volumes if an environment variable with a file path is passed to do so or not. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to do that with the docker-compose syntax easily yet, here is how I went, but the container would not start at all if there is no volume.

- check the launch command with a `docker inspect` on the unpatched container
- change your command with something like this (here using `egorive/seafile-mc:8.0.7-rpi` on a raspberry pi, where the data is on an external disk that might not always be plugged):

```
    volumes:
      - '/data/seafile-data:/shared:Z'
    command: sh -c "( [ -f /shared/.docker-volume-check ] || ( echo volume not mounted, not starting; sleep 60; exit 1 )) && exec /sbin/my_init -- /scripts/start.py"
    restart: always
```

- `touch .docker-volume-check` in the root of your volume

That way, you have a restartable container, that would fail and wait if the volume is not mounted. It also supports volume in a generic way: for instance, when you just create a new container that has not initialized its volume yet with a first setup, it will still boot as you're checking a file you created.